# Webview not showed (only Android 6)

Tags: java, android, webview

i'm using a Webview in my App to show a website with Javascript. I am using this code:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {

}
});
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
     webview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
} else {
        summary = "<html><body>No internet connection!</body></html>";
        webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
}
```

But unfortunately the Webview is not displayed on smarphones with Android 6. (other Android versions are working fine)
On Android 6 here is my LogCat:
http://pastebin.com/fh1Aqp0x

One error I do not understand is:

BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 22202

Do anyone know a solution?

Comment: Probably a permission you missed in the Manifest, android 6 is sensitive to permissions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fortunately solved my problem. The problem was caused by the layout. The superior widget had an foreground-color property. With most Android versions it worked fine, but Android 6 construed the layout in a different way. Now, as I changed my layout, it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check for an app update to Android System WebView with a new Marshmallow device.
Your logcat line 5 indicates you have webview version 44 when the current is 49, which your other devices may have already had.

Comment: this helps me, LOL. many thanks! but how to check it when user's System Webview out of date?

Answer (score 0):

Well try this hope it works. It works for me in Android 6.0

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Book extends AppCompatActivity {

//private Button button;
WebView webView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
    //Get webview
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pa.html");
        }
    });
   }
   class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
   {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
  }

  // Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

  @Override
  // Detect when the back button is pressed
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        // Let the system handle the back button
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Hope this works for you. Do accept the answer if this helps. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can create a WebViewActivity class**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private WebView mWebview;
        private ProgressBar progressBar;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.layout_webview);
            //pass url using intent;
            String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");//it's get the url

            mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarWebView);

            mWebview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            mWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // enable zoom in and out
            mWebview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

            mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                //
                public boolean shuldOverrideKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
                    // Do something with the event here
                    return true;
                }


                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mWebview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }


                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    String hostName = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
                    Log.v("Debug", "Inside override -- url host:" + hostName);

                    if (hostName.equals("https://example.com/risks")) {
                        // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                        return false;

                    }
                    // reject anything other
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mWebview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            mWebview.loadUrl(url);

        }


    }
```

**layout_webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarWebView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** don't forgot to add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```